# How many Riemann surfaces homeomorphic to the sphere are there?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

In a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316181/when-are-two-tori-biholomorphic), I learned that there exist infinitely many non biholomorphic Riemann surfaces homeomorphic to the torus.

Is it also true for the sphere?

Comment: No it's not. In fact the complex structure is unique. (Think of it as $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$) For a proof, do you know Riemann-Roch?

Comment: Any textbook on Riemann surfaces should thoroughly discuss such issues.

Comment: @Sanchez: No, I don't know Riemann-Roch. In fact, I just begin to study Riemann surfaces, so if there is no elementary argument, a little explanation with a reference (for more details) will be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, use the uniformisation theorem and Riemann–Hurwitz.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Why is Riemann-Hurwitz useful? The uniformatisation theorem seems to be sufficient, no?

Comment: The sphere is a surface of genus $0$, so the Hurwitz formula implies there can be no unramified coverings of it by a compact surface of positive genus. Hence the uniformisation theorem implies any Riemann surface that is topologically a sphere must be $\mathbb{C P}^1$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Let $S$ be a Riemann surface homeomorphic so $\mathbb{S}^2$. So $S$ is simply connected, and according to the uniformization theorem, $S$ is either the unit disk, the sphere or the complex plane. But neither the unit disk nor the complex plane are homeomorphic to the sphere, so we can conclude without Riemann-Hurwitz, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, the answer turns out to be an immediate consequence of the uniformization theorem:

> **Theorem:** Every simply connected Riemann surface is biholomorphic to the open unit disk, the complex plane, or the Riemann sphere.

So if $S$ is a Riemann surface homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$, it is simply connected, so biholomorphic to the open unit disk, the complex plane or the Riemann sphere. But a biholomorphism is a homeomorphism and neither the open disk nor the complex plane are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$. Therefore, $S$ is biholomorphic to the Riemann sphere.